# How to rotate css 3d cube in javascript using a button trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, 3d

I have been trying to rotate a css 3-d cube using a button trigger (left) in javascript but I am not sure how animation works in css. 
I tried this jQuery function where #leftBtn is the button I want to rotate the cube by, and renderLeft/rotate are my attempted classes to rotate the shape.
Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heba0/fdqbu841/) with the whole code

```
$("#leftBtn").click(function(event) {    
      $("#front").toggleClass('renderLeft');
      $("#front").toggleClass('rotate');           
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Young David Walsh does a nice little rotating cube that I've used before. You'll find that [here](https://davidwalsh.name/css-cube)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, but I wanted to trigger the rotation manually using a button. I am still not sure how to integrate that with css.